# Unknown websocket slowing site drastically

Tags: reactjs, sockets, webpack, websocket, webpack-2

In a large react project using Webpack I observe a websocket connection that is causing the site to become exceptionally and annoyingly slow. I have tried searching but cannot find the source. I optimisedapi calls and cut them down but this specific websocket call persists and does not get less. Page load is 1.2 s but the finish when the actual loading happens is over 20 s later.

[[image: Dev tools Network tab[1]]

I wanted to know 
1] Does anyone recognize what is happening or it may be a standard method of downloading content ?
2]How can I find what is making this call.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this a screenshot in production?

Because the initiator is [browser-sync-client.js](https://www.browsersync.io/).

BrowserSync uses a websocket connection for hot updating during development.
The initial load states `1.63s` which is recorded, when the page loads initially.

If you are still in development, then there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: It is in dev but, I am trying to improve performance and that can only be done in dev. Also when developing it takes about 30 s to load for every change. Can this be turned off to see the actual speed of the site ?

Comment: Also does the "Load" time reflect the actual load time on production with browser-syn turned off ?

Comment: @AfshinGhazi You can find out more about [DOMContentLoaded & load here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#load). Disabling browser-sync depends on how you initialized it